# open a fragment in a different level of hierarchy with backstack in Android Navigation component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, fragment-backstack, android-deep-link

I am using **Navigation Component** in my project and :

***I need to open a fragment in a different level of  hierarchy, so that the back stack is created properly too***

in my **nav_graph.xml** there is a hierarchy like this:

`HomeFragment -> CollocationFragment -> ChapterFragment --[selfNavigate]--> ChapterFragment  -> PlayerFragment`

as you see one of my fragments **navigates to itself** and send an arguments each time like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/ChapterFragment ">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_chapterFragment_self"
        app:destination="@id/ChapterFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="chapterID"
        app:argType="Long" />

</fragment>
```

in a nutshell, I need to **open PlayerFragment from HomeFragment** with an appropriate **backstack** (the hierarchy mentioned above) .

`HomeFragment ---[my back stack]---> PlayerFragment`

I know that it seems **NavDeepLinkBuilder** creates the backstack itself but I have no idea how to create a custom backstack by using Navigation component for my fragments in this case.

Answer (score 0):

eventually I find a way...it's kind of a workaround but it works like a charm:

so, just call `navigate` function in your desire order to make the hierarchy backstack:

```
 fun openPlayerFromHome(){
    
       findNavController.navigate(R.id.HomeFragment)
       findNavController.navigate(R.id.CollocationFragment)
       findNavController.navigate(R.id.ChapterFragment,bundleOf("chapterID",id))
       findNavController.navigate(R.id.PlayerFragment)
    
    }
```